# SVG rendering issue. SVGs are rendered differently on different Shopify product pages

Tags: svg, shopify, liquid

I've a strange effect with SVGs and have no idea how to handle it.

The SVGs are rendered on Shopify product pages based on metafield values. E.g. when a product has a TRUE in the metafield for vegan, then the SVG for vegan is displayed. I've about 10 metafields for breathable, high-density, repellent, windbreaker etc.

Shopify's metafields are kind of hidden properties and their values can be accessed through Shopify Liquid templating language. On a product page I check e.g. if metafields.product-icons.vegan is TRUE. If yes, the SVG is rendered (the icons in the bottom right).
[image]
The product page above is an example which produces a correct result. Every icon is displayed fully.

My problem is that on some product pages the icons are rendered correctly and on some parts of the SVGs are missing. On the image below. look at the right vegan icon, where the top part is missing:[image]

In this example other parts of the high-density icon in the middle are missing than in the one above, whereas on the first image the icon is complete.  [image]

I checked different machines and networks to see if it's a caching issue. But it isn't.

Every product uses the same template, hence the same liquid code and SVGs.

Any idea what I check further?

Here an example for an SVG which was rendered properly and and with missing parts on two different pages

```html
            <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
                y="0px" viewBox="0 0 76.5 76.5" xml:space="preserve">
            <style type="text/css">
                .st0{display:none;}
                .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;}
                .st2{fill:#FFFFFF;}
                .st3{fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:5;}
                .st4{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;}
                .st5{display:inline;}
                .st6{font-family:'Akkurat-Bold';}
                .st7{font-size:7.0024px;}
                .st8{display:inline;fill:#2B3427;}
                .st9{fill:none;stroke:#2B3427;stroke-width:2;}
                .st10{fill:none;stroke:#2B3427;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;}
                .st11{display:inline;fill:#FFFFFF;}
                .st12{fill:#2B3427;}
            </style>
            <g id="Vorlagen" class="st0">
            </g>
            <g id="Kreis_Black">
                <path d="M38.3,4.8c18.4,0,33.4,15,33.4,33.4s-15,33.4-33.4,33.4S4.8,56.7,4.8,38.3S19.8,4.8,38.3,4.8 M38.3,2.8
                    C18.7,2.8,2.8,18.7,2.8,38.3s15.9,35.4,35.4,35.4s35.4-15.9,35.4-35.4S57.8,2.8,38.3,2.8L38.3,2.8z"/>
                <path d="M38.3,4.8c18.4,0,33.4,15,33.4,33.4s-15,33.4-33.4,33.4S4.8,56.7,4.8,38.3S19.8,4.8,38.3,4.8 M38.3,2.8
                    C18.7,2.8,2.8,18.7,2.8,38.3s15.9,35.4,35.4,35.4s35.4-15.9,35.4-35.4S57.8,2.8,38.3,2.8L38.3,2.8z"/>
            </g>
            <g id="Illu">
                <g>
                    <path class="st1" d="M35.2,43.3c-1.5,1-9.1,3.6-14.7-1.1c-4-3.3-4.4-8.7-3.6-24.9c9.5-0.9,17.4,0.9,22,5c4.1,3.6,3.9,8.6,4.3,11.2
                        C43.6,36.5,39.5,40.4,35.2,43.3z"/>
                    <path class="st2" d="M44.8,41.6c9.7,6,18.3-7.2,20.2-15.9c-5.5-3.6-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6"/>
                    <path class="st3" d="M44.8,41.6c9.7,6,18.3-7.2,20.2-15.9c-5.5-3.6-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6z"/>
                    <path class="st2" d="M44.8,41.6C57.2,51.9,63,36.7,64.9,25.7c-8.2-3.9-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6"/>
                    <path class="st1" d="M44.8,41.6C57.2,51.9,63,36.7,64.9,25.7c-8.2-3.9-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6z"/>
                    <path class="st4" d="M22.7,22.6c0,0,14.8,6,11.3,43.2c0,0,12.4-31.6,24-36.1"/>
                </g>
                <rect x="21.1" y="47.3" class="st2" width="32.6" height="8.1"/>
            </g>
            <g id="Typo" class="st0">
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 25.4238 53.8332)" class="st5 st6 st7">VEGAN</text>
            </g>
            <g id="Typo_Gepfadet">
                <g>
                    <path d="M28.1,53.8h-1l-1.6-5h1l1.2,3.8l1.2-3.8h0.9L28.1,53.8z"/>
                    <path d="M30.8,53.8v-5h3.5v0.8h-2.6v1.2H34v0.8h-2.3V53h2.6v0.8H30.8z"/>
                    <path d="M38.9,53.8l-0.1-0.5c-0.1,0.3-0.6,0.6-1.2,0.6c-0.6,0-1.1-0.1-1.5-0.6c-0.5-0.5-0.6-1.2-0.6-2s0.1-1.5,0.6-2
                        c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.5-0.6c0.6,0,1.1,0.2,1.5,0.6c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.5,1h-0.9c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.3
                        c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.3c-0.3,0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4s0,1.1,0.4,1.5c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.3c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.7-0.3
                        c0.3-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.3-1h-1.2v-0.8h2.1v2.7H38.9z"/>
                    <path d="M44,53.8l-0.3-1h-2l-0.3,1h-0.9l1.7-5h1l1.7,5H44z M42.7,50L42,52.1h1.4L42.7,50z"/>
                    <path d="M49.1,53.8l-2.2-3.4v3.4H46v-5h1l2.1,3.4v-3.4H50v5H49.1z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="Ikons_x5F_Grün" class="st0">
                <path class="st8" d="M38.3,4.8c18.4,0,33.4,15,33.4,33.4s-15,33.4-33.4,33.4S4.8,56.7,4.8,38.3S19.8,4.8,38.3,4.8 M38.3,2.8
                    C18.7,2.8,2.8,18.7,2.8,38.3s15.9,35.4,35.4,35.4s35.4-15.9,35.4-35.4S57.8,2.8,38.3,2.8L38.3,2.8z"/>
                <path class="st8" d="M38.3,4.8c18.4,0,33.4,15,33.4,33.4s-15,33.4-33.4,33.4S4.8,56.7,4.8,38.3S19.8,4.8,38.3,4.8 M38.3,2.8
                    C18.7,2.8,2.8,18.7,2.8,38.3s15.9,35.4,35.4,35.4s35.4-15.9,35.4-35.4S57.8,2.8,38.3,2.8L38.3,2.8z"/>
                <g class="st5">
                    <path class="st9" d="M35.2,43.3c-1.5,1-9.1,3.6-14.7-1.1c-4-3.3-4.4-8.7-3.6-24.9c9.5-0.9,17.4,0.9,22,5c4.1,3.6,3.9,8.6,4.3,11.2
                        C43.6,36.5,39.5,40.4,35.2,43.3z"/>
                    <path class="st2" d="M44.8,41.6c9.7,6,18.3-7.2,20.2-15.9c-5.5-3.6-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6"/>
                    <path class="st3" d="M44.8,41.6c9.7,6,18.3-7.2,20.2-15.9c-5.5-3.6-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6z"/>
                    <path class="st2" d="M44.8,41.6C57.2,51.9,63,36.7,64.9,25.7c-8.2-3.9-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6"/>
                    <path class="st9" d="M44.8,41.6C57.2,51.9,63,36.7,64.9,25.7c-8.2-3.9-13-2.3-17.7,0.6C43.8,28.5,39.2,35,44.8,41.6z"/>
                    <path class="st10" d="M22.7,22.6c0,0,14.8,6,11.3,43.2c0,0,12.4-31.6,24-36.1"/>
                </g>
                <rect x="21.1" y="47.3" class="st11" width="32.6" height="8.1"/>
                <g class="st5">
                    <path class="st12" d="M28.1,53.8h-1l-1.6-5h1l1.2,3.8l1.2-3.8h0.9L28.1,53.8z"/>
                    <path class="st12" d="M30.8,53.8v-5h3.5v0.8h-2.6v1.2H34v0.8h-2.3V53h2.6v0.8H30.8z"/>
                    <path class="st12" d="M38.9,53.8l-0.1-0.5c-0.1,0.3-0.6,0.6-1.2,0.6c-0.6,0-1.1-0.1-1.5-0.6c-0.5-0.5-0.6-1.2-0.6-2s0.1-1.5,0.6-2
                        c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.5-0.6c0.6,0,1.1,0.2,1.5,0.6c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.5,1h-0.9c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.3
                        c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.3c-0.3,0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4s0,1.1,0.4,1.5c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.3c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.7-0.3
                        c0.3-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.3-1h-1.2v-0.8h2.1v2.7H38.9z"/>
                    <path class="st12" d="M44,53.8l-0.3-1h-2l-0.3,1h-0.9l1.7-5h1l1.7,5H44z M42.7,50L42,52.1h1.4L42.7,50z"/>
                    <path class="st12" d="M49.1,53.8l-2.2-3.4v3.4H46v-5h1l2.1,3.4v-3.4H50v5H49.1z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            </svg>
```

Comment: Mt feeling is that you have the same classes with different styles in different svg elements that when used together overwrite one each-other. Also You must know that your code can be written in a simpler way.

Comment: For an easy fix try using presentational attributes instead of styles. I.e: instead of `.st2{fill:#FFFFFF;}` use `<path class="st2" fill="#FFFFFF"`

Comment: the svg s were created by adobe illustrator. Meanwhile I managed to find the property in another icon which caused the problem